Does Matter Cause Curvature or Vice-Versa
From the way explanations about gravity-acceleration-curvature equivalence are usually phrased here or elsewhere, it would appear many or most think that matter causes space-time curvature.
I cannot see how to derive this from observation of celestial motion  alone: Whether you assume that space was bent to begin with so that more stuff accumulated over time—the more so the greater the curvature, hence spots in the universe with a lot of curvature get more massive like a deeper water body would have a greater volume filled—or assume that more stuff gathered makes gravity greater, measurements of celestial bodies' orbits would be identical?
Except saying the chicken (curvature) was there before the egg (matter) yields simpler physics if you can bear to put the question aside as to where it arises from, for a prediction that gravity would increase as you drill into an accumulation of mass like a planetary body whereas the matter-causes-gravity model necessitates an assumption that the earth's core is much denser than the crust.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The actual physics is expressed in math, not words. The equations of general relativity (the Einstein field equations) give a precise relationship between the curvature of spacetime and the stress-energy-momentum tensor. That tensor includes matter as one of its components. This leads to the pop science interpretation that "matter curves spacetime", which is true as far as it goes but leaves out details. Your proposed interpretation that matter accumulates in already curved spacetime would on the other hand not match the equations at all. It's the equations that make the theory (and more importantly are verified by experiment).

How is curvature preceding matter accumulation inconsistent with contemporary modelling when you acknowledge that 'matter curves spacetime' is just sloppy speech? Equivalence implies you can look at it either way?

Yeah OK I should look at the equations to check if matter can be made to go away.

@Prototypist in principle it is possible to solve Einstein's equation by starting from a metric and solving for the energy-momentum tensor, but this is likely to produce unphysical results. Also, the equations are built specifically to describe how the presence of matter and energy curves spacetime, so you cannot remove the contribution of the matter to the curvature.

I am puzzled by the last paragraph--it's been a while since grammar class, but is that subjunctive mood? There is no need to speculate on the density of Earth's core: it's more dense than the planet's average density; moreover, the gravitational field of the Earth is extensively studied, measured, and modeled for science, engineering and military applications.
The modeled field does indeed increase with depth:

If you're asking whether spacetime can be curved (as in "not flat", even though $G_{\mu\nu}=0$) with no matter present, the answer is "yes". This is what a classical blackhole is, of course it was initially made from matter that has since shuffled off the universal coil (it went to the singularity as was deleted), leaving behind mass stored in the self energy of the curvature of spacetime...so maybe it's not the intent of your question.
Otherwise, that $G_{\mu\nu}$ (the Einstein curvature tensor) is a rank-2 symmetric tensor means it can only couple to a rank-2 tensor, and the only one available is the stress-energy tensor.
Now if I have a massive particle ($m$) with velocity $\vec v$, I can make a 4-vector velocity:
$$ u_{\mu} = (\gamma c, \gamma \vec v) $$
which gives me a four momentum ($c=1$):
$$  p_{\mu}=mu_{\mu} = (E, \vec p) $$
and with that, I can make 2 symmetric rank-2 tensors:
$$ m^2\eta_{\mu\nu}$$
$$ S_{\mu\nu} =  p_{\mu}p_{\nu} $$
Forget the former, with the latter, in the rest frame, there is one non-zero component:
$$S_{00} = m^2 $$
(I called it $S$ because this is not quite the stress energy tensor, $T$), but point is: the stress energy is completely dominated by mass for "normal" situations, and geodesic equation reproduces Newtonian gravity to 1st order, and that is fine for most celestial mechanics.
Nevertheless, GR corrections matter for astrophysics and precision spacecraft navigation, and in the latter case, there is a whole formalism: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-Newtonian_expansion to handle it.

There are two problems with this idea:
First, you claim that celestial mechanics in your system would be indistinguishable from the celestial mechanics we observe. This is not necessarily true: If you assume that there are "primordial gravity wells" obeying Newtonian mechanics and that got filled with matter over time, isn't it strange that each of them got filled with exactly the amount of matter that corresponds to its observed motion? Shouldn't we have observed objects which are, say, half-full and therefore deviate significantly from their predicted behaviour based on their observed mass?
Second, what is the mechanism that led to the formation of these gravity wells in the first place? The idea that matter and energy curve spacetime is elegant and does not require any additional assumptions. Lastly, how does this idea explain the Cavendish experiment? Surely, Cavendish cannot have just randomly stumbled upon two gravity wells and happened to fill them precisely with lead spheres, could he?

Two answers: Correct me please but I understand planetary or solar mass(es)  are not measured directly but inferred from gravitational constant + orbital measurements. So the assumption that mass/energy curves space is axiomatic/unproven? The Cavendish experiment I forgot about and will have a think about. Thanks

@Prototypist yes they are, and the entire reason we can do that and build a consistent model using our observations is because there is a direct correspondence between the mass of an object and its gravitational interaction. This correspondence is absent in your model.

Indeed to show my model was not incorrect, a direct correspondence between mass of object & gravitational interaction would have to get refuted.
Indication is higher acceleration at the bottom of a mine shaft but agreed not proof yet. Thanks

Yeah the Cavendish experiment is giving me a headache with this. Perhaps density, customarily considered a property of matter, is nothing but curvature? What wants explaining then is how a collection of atomic (Planck length sized) wells would geometrically arrange to make a bigger one, like one of Cavendish's lead balls. Then matter as something distinct from bent space might be removed from any reasoning about gravity.
PS Zero idea at the moment about how to arrange a bunch of 4d funnels into a bigger one.

Good post on Quora going in the desired direction: https://qr.ae/psB3nL
